# change remember me cookie lifetime dynamically

Tags: symfony, remember-me, fosuserbundle

I am using Symfony2 framework with FOSUserBundle.
I want to change the remember cookie lifetime dynamically: when the user clicks on a link for example.
So I can't just change the value for 'remember_me' in the security.yml file.
I am browsing the Symfony2 API and found Symfony\Component\Security\Http\RememberMe but I can't find achieve my goal.
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

“Remember me” cookie is processed by class [`TokenBasedRememberMeServices`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Http/RememberMe/TokenBasedRememberMeServices.php). Create [Event subscriber](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/event_dispatcher/introduction.html#using-event-subscribers) and call method [`onLoginSuccess`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Http/RememberMe/TokenBasedRememberMeServices.php#L95) from some event listener.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I'm still a bit unclear though. First I should overwrite the onLoginSuccess method so that it uses the 'expires' I want and not the one calculated from the security.yml file. What is the correct way to overwrite the onLoginSuccess method? Then this method should be called when my link is clicked. The Event already exists so I guess I don't need to create a new Event. How do I send the event that triggers onLoginSuccess to be executed?